# Update html on model change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have such controller:

```
function postCtrl($scope){
    $scope.model = { title: 'one' };

    window.setInterval(function(){
        $scope.model += ' more one,';
    }, 1000);
}
```

View side:

```
<div ng-controller="postCtrl">
     <input type="text" ng-model="model.title"/>
</div>
```

I want textbox to automatically refresh value when `model.title` changes (every 1 second). Please tell me if it's possible

Comment: You can also use Angular's $timeout() function instead of setInterval().  $timeout will automatically call $apply() for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model changes, that are applied outside of some AngularJS-observed Context, should be wrapped into scope.$apply(function(){...});

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
       $scope.model += ' more one,';
    });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout) which wraps your function inside a try/catch-block for proper exception handling, and executes a $scope.apply(); for you, and is way easier to test than normal window.setInterval:

```
function postCtrl($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.model = { title: 'one' };

    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.model += ' more one,';
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: thanks Aleksander. kfis answer fits my needs more than yours. Maybe in this particular case your answer is better, but in real code I don't even have setInterval function. Big thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `$scope.$apply` or wrap it around your `$scope.model` assignment.

```
function postCtrl($scope){
    $scope.model = { title: 'one' };

    window.setInterval(function(){
        $scope.model.title += ', 1';
        $scope.$apply();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qeD6Q/

Answer (score -4):

If you're open to using additional libraries, [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) does the exact same thing. You bind a model and whenever the model is updated, the corresponding HTML gets refreshed.

Comment: Thou shall not mix AngularJS and KnockoutJS :)